# Why is my list item calling functions it should not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, react-native

Hi I've build a list component in React Native for my settings page. 
I want each component on the settings page to have a function (in some cases not).

I've created a `array` with `objects` where I place each items attribute.

```
 const list = [
            {
              title: 'Change user settings',
              icon: 'account-circle',
              link: 'UserEdit',
              action: this.noFunction()
            },
            {
              title: 'Logout',
              icon: 'exit-to-app',
              link: 'Auth',
              action: this.sessionFunction()
            },
        ]
```

Right now I've got two list items each with their own function applied to their `action` attribute.

When I press a single `listItem` in my app it calls both functions.

However I want only the function associated to the app be applied.

How can I do this? And what in my code is causing this bug?

```
      noFunction(){
        console.log('noFunction')
      }

      sessionFunction =() => { 
        console.log('sessionFunction')
        this.deleteSession().then(() => {
          this.props.destroySession();
        })
      }

    render(){ 
        const list = [
            {
              title: 'Change user settings',
              icon: 'account-circle',
              link: 'UserEdit',
              action: this.noFunction()
            },
            {
              title: 'Logout',
              icon: 'exit-to-app',
              link: 'Auth',
              action: this.sessionFunction()
            },
        ]
        return (
            <View>
                {
                    list.map((item, i) => (
                    <ListItem
                        key={i}
                        title={item.title}
                        leftIcon={
                            { name: item.icon }
                        }
                        onPress={() => {
                          item.action
                          this.props.navigation.navigate(item.link)
                          }}
                    />
                    ))
                }
            </View>
            )
        }

    }
```

Comment: `action: this.sessionFunction()` *immediately executes* the function, it doesn't assign it to `action`, it assigns the *result* of that function to `action`. And since `sessionFunction` doesn't have a `return` statement, then it assigns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `()` from the functions.

When you have something like `action: this.noFunction()` you are executing the function and assigning it to `action` so `foo.action` will be the value returned from `noFunction` call (wich in you case is undefined because `noFunction` doesn't return anything).

If you pass it like `action: this.noFunction` you only pass the reference to the function and later on you can do `foo.action()` and call `noFunction`.

Comment: That would cause an error with `noFunction`, I think - `undefined is not a function`.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. I did need to add () to the item.action call back. Making it look like item.action()

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the invoke expression `()`.